# Turn off, cancel, camera and microphone permissions in webview

Tags: android, permissions, camera, android-permissions, microphone

Is there a way to revoke, turn off, or cancel camera and mic permissions in the webview once they've been granted to the website?

I had zero idea on how to accomplish this